# background position issue in parallax scrolling in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this common pattern of parallax scrolling with plain javascript that uses custom data attributes and scrolls the background image in the oposite direction.

HTML:

```
  <header id="home" class="section" data-type="background" data-speed="3"></header>
  <section id="portfolio" class="section"></section>
  <section id="about" class="section"></section>
  <section id="contact" class="section"></section>
```

CSS:

```
  #home {
    background-color: grey;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(#000, 0.5), rgba(#000, 0.5)), url("../bg.jpg");
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-position: 50%;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
  }
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
{

    function parallax() {
        Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('*[data-type="background"]')).forEach(e => {

            let yPos = -(window.pageYOffset / e.dataset.speed);

            var coords = `50% ${yPos}px`;

            e.style.backgroundPosition = coords;
        });
    }

    document.addEventListener('scroll', function () {

        parallax();

    });

}
```

The issue is that this code calculates the Ypos variable and assigns it to the background position-y property. Actually it overrides the css which is set to 50% before you start scrolling. As a result the image goes from the center to the bottom once you start scrolling. I have included a codepen to see the problem.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pLvjqR

Is there any way to add the yPos variable to the initialized background position 50% 50%, which means make it 50% 50%+ypos instead of 50% ypos.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I changed the speed of 3 -> .02 and javascript, you have to start at 50% and reduce this percentage rather than applying values in pixels.

```
// let yPos = -(window.pageYOffset / e.dataset.speed);
let yPos = (e.getBoundingClientRect().top - window.pageYOffset) * e.dataset.speed + 50;

// var coords = `50% ${yPos}px`;
var coords = `50% ${yPos}%`;
```

You can view changes here :

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mxyVBV

Comment: There is one more issue. If I add another tag with parallax background lower in the page when I reach it, it should be in its starting position before it starts parallaxing else it going beyond its container's dimensions and repeats itself since i have bg-repeat:repeat. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pLvjqR Here it is

Comment: Oh ! I'm sorry, if the article was lower in the page, the speed would also have been faster... check new fix version : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LdVMga